# Find the length of rope when horse grazes double area

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, area

> A field of grass  $12$ ft by $20$ ft has a horse tied to a corner of the field. The initial length of the rope was $10$ ft but when the horse needed twice as much area over which to graze, the rope was adjusted accordingly.

Now how can I calculate the length of the rope? Do I have to use the Pythagoras theorem to calculate the diagonal of 12 by 20 rectangle? Will  that be the length of the rope? Waiting for your answer :).

Comment: I like very much your "consistence" in "A field of grass 12ft by 20ft consists of a horse..."

Comment: well xd help me with the answer

Comment: From the corner, what will be the shape of the max area that horse can reach?

Comment: i think it will be rectangle

Comment: So if it can go $x$ meter tied to a rope horizontally, why can it go $y (\ne x)$ meter vertically or at any angle for that matter?

Comment: Given it is fixed to a rope, it can move the same max distance in all directions. What shape does that give?

Comment: If the length of the rope is the diagonal, it means the horse grazes all the field, which is too much...

Comment: if the rope is 10ft then the horse can't go all over to 20ft

Comment: same for 12 ft length

Comment: The equation is not easy to solve by hand so I added details and the answer comes to $14.91$ feet (you can say about $15$ feet). But you can do triangle approximation to solve by hand and then fine tune. Please read through my answer for details.

Comment: I wouldn't call a $12 feet \times 20 feet$ a field but a small lawn :)This horse is deemed to die quickly by starvation.

Answer (score 0):

Horse is tied to corner $B$. Initially the horse could reach circular sector BEF of radius $10$. Now it needs double the area so we have a circular sector ($BHG$) and a triangle ($\triangle BCG$).

Add area of both triangle and circular sector. It is double of $25\pi$ which was initial area.

[image]

Say new radius is $r$ and $\angle GBH = \theta,$ then $\angle CGB = \theta$.

$\sin \theta = \displaystyle \frac{BC}{BG} = \frac{12}{r}$

Total area (new) $ \displaystyle = \frac{\theta}{2}r^2 + \frac{1}{2} BC \times CG = \frac{\pi}{4} \times 10^2 \times 2$

$\displaystyle \theta \times r^2 + 12 \times \sqrt{r^2-144} = 100 \pi$

$\displaystyle \arcsin (\frac{12}{r}) \times r^2 + 12 \times \sqrt{r^2-144} = 100 \pi$

Of course this is not trivial to solve. One way is to first approximate using triangle $BGH$.

WolframAplha gives $r \approx 14.911$ ($15$ ft would surely work).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\angle HBG = x = \angle BGC$. $BG = 12 \csc x$

We have

$$ 2\cdot 25\pi = \dfrac{x}{2\pi}\cdot \pi (12\csc x)^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 12 \cdot 12\cot x$$

$$ \Rightarrow x(\csc x)^2 + \cot x = \dfrac{25}{36}\pi$$

WA [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=36%28x%28cot%5E2%28x%29%2B1%29%2Bcot%28x%29%29%3D25+%5Cpi) acute $x \approx 0.9353$

Length of rope [found by WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=12cosec%280.9353%29) is $$ 12\csc x \approx 14.91 \, \text{ft}$$

Comment: Yes as it was complicated, I finally did the equation and added details in my answer. Triangle approximation takes us close though.

Comment: Ah nice! Did WA solve your $\sin^{-1}$ equation? It's good that our answers are matching.